# How do the Cambodians and the rest of the world feel about the Vietnamese invasion (1975-1978)?

Tags: south-east-asia, indochina

Despite the genocide happening in Cambodia, the world seems to be against the Vietnamese invasion. Even ignoring the genocide, Vietnam seems well within their right to retaliate against Cambodia given the repeated border clashing between the countries. Even China, a communist country, was not on Vietnam's side. This is very strange to me. Why was virtually everyone (including the Soviets who aided Vietnam) against the invasion?

Are Cambodians back then and today supportive of the invasion?

My research have not revealed much rationale for the overwhelming anger against the Vietnamese invasion. It appears that Cambodia was China's ally (surprisingly, given that it was not communist) and yet Vietnam was not. Given the circumstances (genocide), it was odd that relatively free countries would join the USA (who was in support of the dictatorship) in condemning the invasion. Wikipedia seems to have plenty of description of what happened but not much about the reason.

From what I have read in a recent news article, one of Cambodia's ministers denies that Vietnam 'invaded', but instead 'saved' them - but also emphasized that Cambodia is not subservient to Vietnam. But I couldn't find another source and this is clearly someone who has the potential to be biased. I'm not sure if the common Cambodians would think the same. –

Comment: What has your research  revealed?  Is this a real question  or political speech?

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot judge or explain the reaction of Cambodians on a single event in history. The 2 nations had been neighbours, friends, ennemies more than 1500 years when Vietnam invaded Cambodia. So whatever they thought of the Khmers rouges, the Vietnamese or even the Chinese was influenced by this history.

Comment: Apologies - I was on my cellphone with limited ability to link.  Like most SE, H:SE expects that you will [document your preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/1401).  Also, like most SE, we discourage [comments](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3882/1401). I will move all your comments into the question; please edit for clarity.

Comment: @Michael This is a good question. I have only seen biased, US sources. They were alarmist - "OMG The dominos!" I am curios what the answer is.

Comment: You are mistaken when you say that  Kampuchea under Khmer Rouge (not Cambodia!)  was non-communist. In order to understand things better, you should read about the split of the Communist movement (roughly from mid-1960s through late 1980s) between supporters of USSR/CPSU and PRC/CCP. Kampuchea was in in the PRC camp and Vietnam was in the USSR camp. In order to understand the position of the Western democracies regarding the war between Kampuchea and Vietnam you should read more about the history of Cold War, past https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Nixon%27s_1972_visit_to_China.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question i about current sentiment on a past event - which is politics and/or journalism rather than history.

Comment: The USSR urged Vietnam to invade Kampuchea in order to overthrow the pro-PRC Khmer Rouge, which they did successfully, so Cambodians obviously liked it. But the PRC disliked it greatly and in revenge began the [Sino-Vietnamese War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Vietnamese_War), Feb.—March 1979. The war lasted 3 weeks, but was extremely severe, total 60,000 dead and 60,000 wounded.